# Boot Menu - Multi Linux OS installation

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I am a standard PC ***user***, interested in and trying out Linux OS.

I have the following installation on a 1 TB HDD (exclusive for Linux OS) -

**Ubuntu 23.04** (/dev/sdd1 - EFI; /dev/sdd2 - /, /dev/sdd3 - /home); Flag - `boot,esp`

**Linux Mint Cinnamon 21.2** (/dev/sdd4 - EFI; /dev/sdd5 - /, /dev/sdd6 - /home); Flag - `boot,esp`

**Kubuntu 23.04** (/dev/sdd7 - EFI; /dev/sdd8 - /, /dev/sdd9 - /home); Flag - `boot,esp`

**Ubuntu Studio 22.04.3 LTS** (/dev/sdd10 - EFI; /dev/sdd11 - /, /dev/sdd12 - /home); Flag - `bios_grub`

**Swap** (/dev/sdd13); Flag - `swap`

Installation sequence was Ubuntu then Linux Mint then Kubuntu then Ubuntu Studio

My query:

Why is Ubuntu Studio flagged `bios_grub` whereas the others are flagged `boot,esp`?

What error, if any, did I make while installing the last OS i.e., Ubuntu Studio? And, if it is indeed an error, can this be corrected without requiring re-installation of the OS?

Comment: are you able to launch any of these systems from the boot menu which appears after switching on?

Answer (score 0):

Grub is a linux Multiboot Loader.
[Ubuntu Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2?_ga=2.77810452.1249763795.1695215976-186635787.1694934885)

I can be configured.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of your Ubuntu Studio it seems the Bootloader was installed incorrectly using MBR (Master Boot Record) as opposed to EFI.

ESP refers to EFI System Partition, hence everything else was installed with EFI, but your studio which was installed using the older BIOS MBR method.

You can theoretically fix that, by reinstalling grub (the bootloader, not the package) in your Ubuntu studio, but if you are new to the process and your system works anyway I suggest your refrain from doing that.

That being said if you decide to be adventurous I would refer you to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB) documentation page on GRUB, for instructions on how to reinstall it (it is the most detailed documentation I am aware of). It has a section specifically for UEFI systems with detailed instructions, better than the [Canonical equivalent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing).

The bit you're interested the most in is the following, but read the accompanying documentation carefully.

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp --bootloader-id=GRUB
```

Comment: BTW one thing I find rather odd is that there are multiple ESP partitions. Usually one partition is re-used by multiple bootloaders, with different names. Also in most cases you only one GRUB installation.

Comment: You should only have one ESP per drive/device. And all installs must be in same boot mode or all UEFI or all old BIOS boot mode. Drives should be gpt partitioned, not very old MBR. The only time MBR is required now is if installing Windows in old BIOS boot mode. But Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012, so all systems since then are UEFI.